# How to remove properties from excel workbook with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am sure there is a duplicate of this question, but not of the issue I am having, nor have I found any answers that helped resolved my issue. I am running this on both Windows and Mac. I am trying to remove certain properties from an excel file using `openpyxl`. Before running `wb.save(wb)`, I am able to confirm that the current working workbook's properties are correctly updated. Upon saving the file with `wb.save(wb)` and then opening the file or `core.xml`, I am still seeing the properties I am trying to remove. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to achieve this by editing `core.xml` directly with a script that doesn't involve any new 3rd party libraries?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.packaging.core import DocumentProperties
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook


def set_last_mod_by(wb: Workbook):
    props = wb.properties
    new_props = DocumentProperties()
    props_to_reset = ['lastModifiedBy', 'last_modified_by']

    for prop in dir(props)[34:]:
        if prop in props_to_reset:
            setattr(new_props, prop, None)
        else:
            setattr(new_props, prop, getattr(props, prop))

    return new_props


def main():
    location_path = 'Desktop'
    file_name = 'Test_Report'
    file_type = '.xlsx'
    full_path = f'{location_path}{file_name}{file_type}'

    wb = load_workbook(filename=full_path)
    wb.properties = set_last_mod_by(wb)
    wb.save(f'{location_path}{file_name}_Copy{file_type}')
    print('Done!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have also tried the following which did not result in the file opening with the new property values:

```
wb = load_workbook()
wb.properties.lastModifiedBy = None
wb.save(wb)
```

Comment: The code looks weird, but I suspect the condition is never being met due to the slicing. Please submit a bug report if you think there is a bug in the library.